# Given two numbers, decide if one is the parent of the other in a binary tree

Tags: java, tree, binary

I'm trying to take two numbers input by a user and tell if one is the parent of the other. For example, in my tree, the number 48 is the child of 61, so I would like to print that 61 is the parent. But if I took two numbers like 70 and 49, the program would print that 70 is not the parent.

[image]

So far the method I'm using looks like this:

```
static void findParent(Node node, int val, int parent)
    {
        if (node == null)
            return;

// If current node is the required node
        if (node.value == val)
        {

// Print its parent
        System.out.println(parent);
        
        
        }
        else
        {
            
// Recursive calls for the children
// of the current node
// Current node is now the new parent
            findParent(node.left, val, node.value);
            findParent(node.right, val, node.value);
            
        }
        
    

                
    }
```

I'm able to find the parents of whatever node I choose, but I can't figure out how to add in a case where the user inputs numbers that don't work. I was thinking of returning some ints and comparing them to the user input but I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Here's the code from my main driver class where I try calling the method:

```
System.out.println("Enter the possible ancestor:");
                int x = scn.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter the possible child:");
                int y = scn.nextInt();
                
                
                
                if(bt.containsNode(x))
                {
                    if(bt.containsNode(y))
                    {
                        bt.findParent(bt.root, y ,x);
                        /*if(bt.findParent(bt.root, y ,x) == x)
                        {
                            System.out.println(x + " Is the parent");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println(x + " is NOT the parent");
                        }*/
                    
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("The child you entered does not exist.");
                    }
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("The parent you entered does not exist.");
                }
```

bt refers to the class that the findParent method is located along with all my other methods.

Comment: I think you are asking if the first node is the ancestor of the second node.  If the user enters 61 for ancestor and 60 for descendant, it should return true.  If the user enter 66 for ancestor and 60 as descendant, it should return false.  I think that's what I got from reading your problem description and looking at your code.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather not start two recursive searches for both children. Instead, I'd add a parent field to each node and manually fill it when needed:

```
    class Node {
        int value;
        Node left;
        Node right;

        Node parent; //will populate manually
    }

    void preprocess(List<Node> nodes) {
        nodes
            .stream()
            .forEach(node -> {
                if (node.left != null) node.left.parent = node;
                if (node.right != null) node.right.parent = node;
            });
    }
```

This way, you can conduct a straight search from the bottom node up until the top one (e.g. when you're trying to find if 48 is the parent of 51, you check 51 -> 49 -> 59 -> 48):

```
    boolean isParent(Node node, int potentialParentValue) {
        if (node == null) {
            return false
        };
        if (node.value == potentialParentValue) {
            return true
        };
        return isParent(node.parent, potentialParentValue);
    }
```

And the example code that creates the whole tree you have in the example and prints the results:

```
    Node n52 = new Node(52, null, null);
    Node n51 = new Node(51, null, n52);
    Node n49 = new Node(49, null, n51);
    Node n60 = new Node(60, null, null);
    Node n59 = new Node(59, n49, n60);
    Node n48 = new Node(48, null, n59);
    Node n75 = new Node(75, null, null);
    Node n70 = new Node(70, null, n75);
    Node n66 = new Node(66, null, n70);
    Node n61 = new Node(61, n48, n66);
    List<Node> nodes = Arrays.asList(n52, n51, n49, n60, n59, n48, n75, n70, n66, n61);

    void searchForParent(List<Node> nodeList, int nodeVal, int potentialParent) {
        preprocess(nodeList);

        Optional<Node> initialNode = nodeList
            .stream()
            .filter(node -> node.value == nodeVal)
            .findFirst();

        if (!initialNode.isPresent()) { //add the same search for potential parent if needed
            System.out.println(String.format("Node %s does not exist", nodeVal));
            return;
        }

        boolean checkParent = isParent(initialNode.get(), potentialParent);
        System.out.println(String.format("Value %s %s among the parents of node with value %s",
                potentialParent, (checkParent ? "is": "is not"), nodeVal));
    }

    searchForParent(nodes, 48, 61); //Value 61 is among the parents of node with value 48
    searchForParent(nodes, 51, 48); //Value 48 is among the parents of node with value 51
    searchForParent(nodes, 70, 49); //Value 49 is not among the parents of node with value 70
    searchForParent(nodes, 49, 60); //Value 60 is not among the parents of node with value 49
    searchForParent(nodes, 30, 60); //Node 30 does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform a double search, i.e. lookup the two numbers at the same time (two comparisons instead of one).

If you reach one of the numbers, continue the search for other number, from this node as a root.

Otherwise, if the directions (left or right) become different, you can answer negatively.

Standard search:

```
if root == NULL 
    return NULL
if number == root->data 
    return root->data
if number < root->data 
    return search(root->left)
else
    return search(root->right)
```

Double search:

```
if root == NULL 
    return NULL
if numberA == root->data 
    return root->data
if numberB == root->data 
    return root->data
if numberA < root->data 
    if numberB < root->data 
        return search(root->left)
    else 
        return NULL
else 
    if numberB > root->data 
        return search(root->right)
    else 
        return NULL
```